# How to execute and save sql parameterized query in ssis?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledbcommand

I've driving mad with this...
I have a parametrized query to extract some information from a data source, but first, I obtain via OLE DB Source those parameters I need to make my query, them I need to do the query and save both the parameters and the result y my fact table.

More explanations, I have projects and dates, my dimensions, I need a metric, my fact, resulting of a query ( i have the query it works in sql server) that has as parameters the project and the date, and returns the metric.
My ETL idea was like this: Ole DB Source -> Ole DB Command (because it supports parametrized query) -> Ole DB Destination

But them I discover, OLE DB Command does not have and out put, I've been trying other ways but I dont know how, please, help!!!
Anabel

Comment: so are you trying to execute a stored procedure in the Ole DB Command? Or is the problem that you need to output from the Ole DB Command?  Can you please edit this statement:  "But them I discover, OLE DB Command does not have and out put..."  Im a bit confused on what you are saying here.

Comment: Are you using SSIS or C# or vb.net?

Comment: No store procedures, just a simple parameterize sql query, I need to to pull several projects and dates combinatios, and them pass the to an sql query. I thought at first that ole db command has output, so I just make my query and the result of the query wil be pass in the output of sql command, I work with ssis. Any other ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of work, I did what CognitiveBI suggest, but I used a for loop container to repeat the process all the times I need,

First, I used a container with a data flow that save in an stage table, all my projects and dates combinations, an also a current row iqual to 1 for every row,

Second I did the procedure for the first row with current equal to 1, I did all with Execute Sql Task Component, using variables as CognitiveBi suggest.

Third, I include al my sql tasks, in a loop container, and configured as it says here, http://www.sqlis.com/post/For-Loop-Container-Samples.aspx, to loop for my projects, my last sql task, put the current row to o, so the next iteration, goes with the next row.

Finally, I made another container that pulls the data for the stage table and finally I erase the stage table,
It works find for me, Thanks for the ideas that take me to the solutions, 
Anabel

Answer (score 0):

If your first OLE DB is just returning one Project and one Date, which need to be passed to the second query (your OLE DB Command), then I would suggest:

1. In the Control Flow (not the Data Flow Task)
2. Create two variables:  v_project, v_date
3. Use an Execute SQL Task in the control flow
       SELECT myproject, mydate FROM A
   In the Execute SQL Task:
       -- General Tab, set 'ResultSet' to 'Single Row'
       -- Results Set tab to send myproject to v_project and mydate to v_date
4. Connect the Execute SQL Task to your Data Flow Task, so it will run first and populate the variables.
5. In your Data Flow Task:
    Start with an Ole DB Source
     Write your query to accept paramters
         SELECT * FROM B WHERE project = ? and projectdate = ?
     In the 'Parameters' set each one to use the variables your created earlier.

6 go on with data flow tasks until your destination.

Note: Since the question was not specific, this answer is assuming you only want to pass in 1 project and 1 date.  If you need to pass multiple project/date combinations then there are other answers.   I use this method all the time when I need to pull a last load date for an ETL project.

Comment: I have to pass multiple project/dates comibinatios, I have to pull the project and date first and them make a query in sql, (no store procedure) to obtain the rest of the data, what other solutions do you have??

Comment: I have to pass multiple project/dates comibinatios, I have to pull the project and date first and them make a query in sql, (no store procedure) to obtain the rest of the data, what other solutions do you have??